# tcl twapi 4.2.12 package require error

Tags: tcl

I am trying to use the twapi 4.2.12 package posted at https://sourceforge.net/projects/twapi/. 
It gave me an error `attempt to provide package twapi 4.2.12 failed: package twapi 4.1.27 provided instead`  on `package require twapi` command. Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: What happens if you require the package without the version number?

Comment: My guess is that you have a version clash, between a `pkgIndex.tcl` announcing one version, and the `source`'d/ `load`'ed extension announcing the other. How did you deploy the downloaded extension exactly?

Comment: @Peter Lewerin, I am using package require without version number.